Suppress Logger output from EF Core SQL when using NLog
I am trying to get EF Core to stop writing SQL to my log files. I am using NLog. I have the following in my appsettings.json:
"Logging":
{
    "LogLevel":
    {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Warning"
    }
},

I tried setting the following when creating the context:
    services.AddDbContext<TContext>(o =>
    {
        o.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        o.ConfigureWarnings(c => c.Log((RelationalEventId.CommandExecuting, LogLevel.Warning)));
    });

And I tried something like this when adding the logging:
    services.AddLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
        logging.AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        logging.AddNLog();
        logging.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning);
    });

Every time is still logs the Info for the logging:
2024-11-20 15:13:36.3284||INFO|Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command|Executed DbCommand (34ms)...

What am I missing?

Your code looks correct; here are my suggestions.

My best guess is that something you may have specified in the Nlog config is overriding the configurations in appsettings.json.

To test this, could you add the following inside services.AddLogging()? Since this filter is at the code level, It should help override NLog settings.
logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", LogLevel.Warning);

Do you have an Nlog.config file, and if so, confirm if a more permissive rule is specified for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command?


I added the logging using code because I needed to specify an output folder for the log file and did not know how to do that using a log file. All my config is done with code. And I tried that AddFilter as you have it, even just with "Microsoft" to see if it would suppress any logs that start with that, but no affect. It makes me wonder, as you said, if something somewhere else is making changes.

@TyrelVanNiekerk take a look at this https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4927

Thanks, that looks promising. I will take a look.

See also NLog v5 - Release Notes - LoggingProvider without filters
